# Can I recharge a lead-acid battery directly using a DC-DC step-up module (150 W)?

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, charger

I would like to make a simple lead-acid battery charger using a DC-DC step up module (150 W).

I have adjusted the output to 13.5 V.

Can I connect it directly to the battery, or should I use some kind of resistance to keep the battery?

Comment: Does your module have adjustable current limit? What capacity is the battery, and what type (eg. SLA, AGM)?

Comment: To charge a "12 volt" lead-acid battery, you will need to supply a bit over 14 volts and will need some current limiting.  What is the source of power you intend to use to charge the battery?

Comment: the module does not have current limit @BruceAbbott

Comment: @PeterBennett the DC-DC module

Comment: But what is providing power to the DC-DC module?

Comment: @PeterBennett I missed the DC-DC part. This sounds like a rather unusual setup to charge a lead-acid battery. This is potentially going to draw a hefty current from a lower voltage power source.

Comment: You need to specify battery capacity, battery type (vehicle flooded gel ...), Voltage input, energy source, ... |  You need to limit maximum current - using a resistor is not usually the best way in situations like this. Maximum details will best help us help you .

Comment: @amr we need to know the spec of the power source for your DC-DC converter and the spec of the lead-acid battery you want to charge in order to provide a meaningful answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this basic setup to charge a lead acid battery. The voltage should be set between 12.9V and 14.1V.

The are a number of subtleties around lead acid (or any other) battery charging which are worth studying once you develop a bit more expertise. You can find these by Googling around. Take a look [here](https://www.powerstream.com/SLA.htm#:%7E:text=The%20typical%20charging%20voltage%20is,battery%20without%20overcharging%20or%20damage) and [here](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lead_based_batteries) for some more detail.

Comment: i have read this by googling as what u r saying ,i was asking if i should add a resistance or what should i add as current limiting ?

Comment: Not really a correct answer, It needs to be specified that the power supply should be able to limit the current, preferable below 1C of the battery (check the battery datasheet).

Comment: @amr current limiting will require additional circuitry beyond the simple setup you are describing in your question. What is the spec of your lead-acid battery? The charge current will need to limited to way below 1C as this could be 10-100A depending on battery size.

Comment: @mhaselup the DC-DC module has variable resistor for limiting the current,for the battery it is 12V 29 AH